# Search in Magento products error: Invalid filter type

Tags: magento2, frontend, catalogsearch

I am using Magento 2.2 and a custom theme. When using the frontend search, I am getting the following exception (URL e.g. /catalogsearch/result/?q=Tshirt)

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid filter type

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid filter type
#0 /var/www/vhosts/sanodo.de/maintenance.sanodo.de/vendor/magento/framework/Search/Request/Cleaner.php(113): Magento\Framework\Search\Request\Cleaner->cleanFilter('visibility_filt...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/sanodo.de/maintenance.sanodo.de/vendor/magento/framework/Search/Request/Cleaner.php(212): Magento\Framework\Search\Request\Cleaner->cleanQuery('visibility')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/sanodo.de/maintenance.sanodo.de/vendor/magento/framework/Search/Request/Cleaner.php(92): Magento\Framework\Search\Request\Cleaner->processQueryReference(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/sanodo.de/maintenance.sanodo.de/vendor/magento/framework/Search/Request/Cleaner.php(57): Magento\Framework\Search\Request\Cleaner->cleanQuery('quick_search_co...')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/sanodo.de/maintenance.sanodo.de/vendor/magento/framework/Search/Request/Builder.php(142): Magento\Framework\Search\Request\Cleaner->clean(Array)

...
```

I could not find any information on this error.

Comment: the same error here. how you solved it?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not, but I am using Algolia search now, so we are not relying on the magento search anymore. I can really recommend it, if you havn't tried it yet. And for our usage it's free.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution (for me) on github (https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/1114)

I had to resave the product attribute "Visibility" and clear the cache afterwards. That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the custom attribute  created. Had to delete the attribute and create again. Worked for me!