# Magento 2 catalog search result

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, search-result

I re-enabled the frontend global search and while the autocomplete suggestion work, any query returns the following error.

I do notice the URL search does look like this when clicking any suggestion

domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=+truffle

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid filter type
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid filter type
/www/vendor/magento/framework/Search/Request/Cleaner.php(113): Magento\Framework\Search\Request\Cleaner->cleanFilter('visibility_filt...')
/www/vendor/magento/framework/Search/Request/Cleaner.php(212): Magento\Framework\Search\Request\Cleaner->cleanQuery('visibility')
```

When I dug deep, and check that class the visibility_filter did exist.  Is there some additional catalog search setting that needs to be changed?

I have been stump for a couple days now.

Similar to Unanswered overflow question (link below).

[Search in Magento products error: Invalid filter type](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215907/search-in-magento-products-error-invalid-filter-type)

Comment: I have the same problem. how you solved it?